Service linked to Facebook page that I can't remove
I manage a Facebook page for the the charity I volunteer for. Whilst changing a setting today, I noticed that FB is claiming I have a service linked to my page called "HeyOrca". This is a service I've never heard of, and 100% didn't link. It's possible, but extremely unlikely, another page admin did this, but before I get into that I just want to remove it.

Clicking through the "Edit" button gives me a link to the "business integration" settings to remove it, but the link just takes me to the main settings page.
If I follow online instructions for viewing web and app integrations (Profile | Settings and Privacy | Settings | Apps and Websites), there is nothing showing to remove.

Where can I view the settings for this service and remove it?
